# apa style and citing both in text as at the end of a sentence

Tags: citing, apa-style, bibliographystyle

Currently, I am using `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}`. This enables me to cite in text with `\citet{xxx}` and cite at the end of a sentence with `\citep{xxx}`. Furthermore, the reference list at the end of my document is alphabetically ordered based on an author's last name. However, the reference list shows the first letter of the author's first name at the beginning of each line, which does not have my preference. The reference style is shown in the image below: [image: abbrvnat reference style]

I would like to have my reference list in APA style. However, still be able to both cite in-text ( the Einstein journal paper (1905) ...) as cite at the end of a sentence (Einstein, 1905).

Can someone help me with this?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is there something stopping you from ditching the `abbrvnat` bib style and adopting a bib style that follows APA formatting guidelines? By the way, "APA style" is not exactly unique. Can you narrow it down a bit? Incidentally, do you employ the `natbib` citation management package at present?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `biblatex`, the `apa` style and   `natbib` citation styles.

(`\citefield{A-reference}{title}` from `biblatex`)

[image: b]

Try this code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{jobname67.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    keywords =     "physics"
}
        
    @book{knuth,
        author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
        title        = {The {\TeX book}},
        date         = 1984,
        maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
        volume       = {A},
        publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
        location     = {Reading, Mass.},
        langid       = {english},
        langidopts   = {variant=american},
    }   
    
    @book{companion,
        author       = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
        title        = {The {LaTeX} Companion},
        date         = 1994,
        edition      = 1,
        publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
        location     = {Reading, Mass.},
        pagetotal    = 528,
        langid       = {english},
        langidopts   = {variant=american},
    }
    
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
language=auto,
style=apa,
natbib=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{jobname67.bib} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

In this document there are three cited items:

\textit{\citefield{companion}{title}}  book \citep{companion}, the \citeauthor{einstein}'s journal paper (\citeyear{einstein}) and other \LaTeX\ related items  like \citet{companion} and a nice \citeauthor{knuth}`s book \citep{knuth}.

\printbibliography  
    
\end{document}
```